# Program failing to call void function

Tags: c++, function, void

I am having trouble with writing this program. My issue seems to be with the processOrder and displayOrder functions, upon running this code the getOrder function runs just fine, but the program doesn't call the other functions at all and just terminates after the data has been entered. I'm sure I am missing something simple, but I can't see it, any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct Order {
    string name;
    double unitPrice;
    int quantity;
    double totalPrice;
};

const int NumOrder = 3;
Order GetOrder();
void ProcessOrder(Order& myOrder);
void DisplayOrders(Order orderList[]);

int main()
{

    Order orderList[NumOrder];

    for (int i = 0; i < NumOrder; i++) {
        // create an order variable
        Order myOrder;

        cout << "Enter information for order #" << i + 1 << ": " << endl;
        // call GetOrder() function to enter order’s information
        myOrder = GetOrder();

        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        cout << endl;

        // call ProcessOrder() function to update total price of an order
        void ProcessOrder(Order & myOrder);

        // add the new order in the order array
        orderList[i] = myOrder;
    }
    // call DisplayOrders() function to display all of three orders’ information
    void DisplayOrders(Order orderList[]);

    return 0;
}

Order GetOrder()
{
    Order myOrder;

    cout << "Item Nane: ";
    getline(cin, myOrder.name);
    cout << "Unit Price: ";
    cin >> myOrder.unitPrice;
    cout << "Quantity: ";
    cin >> myOrder.quantity;

    myOrder.totalPrice = 0.00;

    return myOrder;
}

void ProcessOrder(Order& myOrder)
{
    myOrder.totalPrice = (myOrder.quantity * myOrder.unitPrice) + (myOrder.quantity * myOrder.unitPrice) * 0.007;
}

void DisplayOrders(Order orderList[NumOrder])
{
    // complete function definition here
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < NumOrder; j++) {
        string iName = orderList[j].name;
        cout << "Item name: " << iName << endl;
        cout << "Unit price: $" << orderList[j].unitPrice << endl;
        cout << "Quantity: " << orderList[j].quantity << endl;
        cout << "Total price: $" << orderList[j].totalPrice << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `void ProcessOrder(Order & myOrder);` is a function declaration not a call. To call write: `ProcessOrder(myOrder);`

Comment: Thank you very much. Jeez, I knew it was something small. After correcting the calls everything seems to be working now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

to put it simply:

```
void ProcessOrder(Order & myOrder);
```

and

```
void DisplayOrders(Order orderList[]);
```

are functions declaration. ie: you're declaring functions with these lines, not calling already declared ones.
In this context, use these instead:

```
ProcessOrder(myOrder);
DisplayOrders(orderList);
```

if you're new to c++, I advise you to visit this [link](https://www.sololearn.com/Course/CPlusPlus/), it's a good way to learn efficiently with applications.

Hope this was helpful.